# Clustering algorithm performance check on un plot able data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am using Kmeans Clustring algorithm from **Sci-kit** learn library and dimension of my data is *169* and that's why I am unable to visualize the result of clustering.

Is there any way to measure the performance of algorithm?

Secondly, I have the labels of data and I want to test the learned model with the test dataset but I am not sure the labels Kmeans algo gave to cluster coincide with the labels I have.

Comment: Focus on one of your questions and provide an example of code you've tried. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Bear in mind that in high dimension, the euclidean distance becomes very bad at judging whether two points are near or distant. Everything basically has the same euclidean distance in high dimensions. [Cross validated has some links on that topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions)

Comment: You might make a table of cluster vs label (confusion matrix). Also,    you could try visualizing in lower dimensions - for example, project to the first two principal components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways of visualizing high dimensional data. You can sample some dimensions, use PCA components, MDS, tSNE, parallel coordinates, and many more.

If you even just read the Wikipedia article on clustering, there is a section on evaluation, including supervised as well as unsupervised evaluation. But the results of such evaluation can be *very* misleading...

Bear on mind that if you have labeled data, supervised methods should always outperform unsupervised methods that do not have the labels: they don't know what to look for - there is lie reason to believe that every clustering happens to align with some labels. In particular, on most data there will be many reasonable clusterings that capture different aspects of your data.